# Simular pressionamento de tecla - Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

Olá,
estou com problemas em enviar o pressionamento de tecla em um jogo,

estou usando o delphi, testei funções como:

```
  SendMessage(hdle_do_game, WM_KEYDOWN , ord('a'), 0);
   keybd_event(65,0,0,0);
SendMessage(hdle_do_game, WM_CHAR, ord('a'), 0);
```

e o jogo simplesmente não reconhece em sua interface, apenas em áreas de chatbox, entretanto, o teclado virtual do windows funciona em todo o jogo

alguma sugestão? Grato!

Comment: Boa tarde Daniel, tente usar keybd_event(Ord('a'), 0, KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, 0);

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário Pablo, estou usando a versão 7 do delphi, aqui não foi declarado a constante KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, mas percebi em  rotinas na internet na internet que equivale a 4. Então comecei a testar esses parâmetros, 
para a minha surpresa, fiz um loop de 0 a 255, enviando a instrução assim:
keybd_event(1,i,1,0);
o resultado foi que o jogo reconhceu as teclas que eu preciso, mas nao corresponde ao ASCII, até faz sentido já que o jogo foi desenvolvido na coreia, vou tentar encontrar as keys que eu preciso agora...obrigado por resolver meu problema

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a função GetASyncKeyState(key) do pacote winapi.Windows:

```
procedure TForm2.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   if isKeyPress(17) then begin
      showMessage('telcla Ctrl pressionada');
   end;

end;

function TForm2.IsKeyPress(const Key: integer): boolean;
begin
   Result := GetASyncKeyState(Key) <> 0;
end;
```